# How to Search User in Active Directory using LDAP in Asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, active-directory, ldap-query

How can I fetch all the record from my Active Directory Server in asp.net c#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a connection string in **LDAP** providing **username** and **Password** which can communicate with the server and have Administrator rights.

Suppose DC is **me.com** and **username** and **password** are the password of that user Id which is having **Administrator rights**.

```
   DirectoryEntry rootDSE = rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU="",OU=" ",dc="me",dc=com", username, password);

    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(rootDSE);

    search.PageSize = 1001;// To Pull up more than 100 records.

     search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))";//UserAccountControl will only Include Non-Disabled Users.
      SearchResultCollection result = search.FindAll();

         foreach (SearchResult item in result)
        {
            if (item.Properties["cn"].Count > 0)
            {
                DisplayName = item.Properties["cn"][0].ToString();
            }
            if (item.Properties["mail"].Count > 0)
            {
                EmailAddress = item.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
            }
            if (item.Properties["SamAccountName"].Count > 0)
            {
                DomainName = item.Properties["SamAccountName"][0].ToString();
            }
            if (item.Properties["department"].Count > 0)
            {
                Department = item.Properties["department"][0].ToString();
            }
            if (item.Properties["title"].Count > 0)
            {
                title = item.Properties["title"][0].ToString();
            }
            if (item.Properties["company"].Count > 0)
            {
                company = item.Properties["company"][0].ToString();
            }
            if (item.Properties["DistinguishedName"].Count > 0)
            {
                memberof = item.Properties["DistinguishedName"][0].ToString();
            }
            if (item.Properties["AccountExpirationDate"].Count > 0)
            {
                string aaa = item.Properties["AccountExpirationDate"][0].ToString();
            }

              dt.Rows.Add(DisplayName, EmailAddress, DomainName, Department, title, company, memberof);
             DisplayName = string.Empty;
             EmailAddress = string.Empty;
             DomainName = string.Empty;
             Department = string.Empty;
             title = string.Empty;
             company = string.Empty;
             memberof = string.Empty;

               rootDSE.Dispose();
```

In this way we can Pull up all the records from our Domain Server.