# How to get rid of DirectoryServicesCOMException while searching in Active Directory using C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I know how to fetch data from Active Directory using C# and `System.DirectoryService`. I have a sample here:

```
var rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://mydomain.local", "UserName", "Password");
var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootentry);
searcher.CacheResults = false;
searcher.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree;
searcher.PageSize = 1000;
searcher.Filter = "Some LDAP Query";
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new[] { "objectguid", "name", "objectclass" });
var result = searcher.FindAll();
var enumerator = result.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())  // THIS LINE THROWS AN EXCEPTION
{
   // Do my work here
}
```

However `enumerator.MoveNext()` throws an exception most of the time but not everytime. Details of the exception are given as follows:

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007202C): The server does not support the requested critical extension.
>
> at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.ResultsEnumerator.MoveNext()

Unfortunately, I am unable to figure the conditions under which the exception is thrown. Please help me out here! **How can I get rid of this exception?**

Thanking in advance.

PS: I have viewed the following StackOverflow articles but those do not answer my particular question.

[fetch active directory user data using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55951799/fetch-active-directory-user-data-using-c-sharp)

[How to Search User in Active Directory using LDAP in Asp.net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285196/how-to-search-user-in-active-directory-using-ldap-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

*I am not an Active Directory expert so please don't assume any knowledge. Thanks!*

I am trying to execute the following LDAP Query:

```
(&(!cn=SystemMailbox{e0dc1c29-89c3-4034-b678-e6c29d823ed9})(!cn=SystemMailbox{1f05a927-f7a0-4bff-ba0e-7400efadb1d7})(!cn=FederatedEmail.4c1f4d8b-8179-4148-93bf-00a95fa1e042)(!cn=DiscoverySearchMailbox{D919BA05-46A6-415f-80AD-7E09334BB852})(!cn=SystemMailbox{1f05a927-fb80-4c7c-8a53-b072e381d13a})(!cn=SystemMailbox{bb558c35-97f1-4cb9-8ff7-d53741dc928c})(!cn=Migration.8f3e7716-2011-43e4-96b1-aba62d229136)(!cn=SystemMailbox{1f05a927-594f-4c55-a9ca-99486880acb5})(!cn=SystemMailbox{1f05a927-1b66-4473-9aec-cf049b8cef3d})(!cn=SystemMailbox{D0E409A0-AF9B-4720-92FE-AAC869B0D201})(!cn=SystemMailbox{2CE34405-31BE-455D-89D7-A7C7DA7A0DAA})(!cn=SystemMailbox{1f05a927-9350-4efe-a823-5529c2d64109})(!cn=SystemMailbox{1f05a927-c92b-414e-aeb0-1256cedb2cfb})(!cn=SystemMailbox{8cc370d3-822a-4ab8-a926-bb94bd0641a9})(!cn=SystemMailbox{1f05a927-eac1-46e7-9a47-611e1a81bb50})(!cn=SystemMailbox{1f05a927*)(|(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))(objectClass=group)(&(objectClass=contact)(objectCategory=person))(&(objectClass=publicFolder)(objectCategory=publicFolder))(&(objectClass=computer)(objectCategory=computer))(objectCategory=container)(objectCategory=domain)(objectCategory=organizationalUnit))(!name=System)(!name=Microsoft Exchange System Objects)(!name=ForeignSecurityPrincipals))
```

Comment: Why not iterate using a foreach loop as in `foreach (SearchResult r in result){ ... }` ?

Comment: @Theo why would that make any difference since the foreach loop will be compiled as the same `MoveNext` over the enumerable?

Comment: Did you try? Still errors?

Comment: @Theo yes I tried and, as expected, it gives the same error in foreach loop.

Comment: @Theo Now I have came across a way to reproduce the issue. Actually I am dealing with an environment containing hundreds of millions of objects. But, in order to simulate this problem in a small environment (but containing objects over 1000), do the following:
- Insert break point at first line inside foreach

- Pause (i.e., don't step over) for 30 minutes

- Resume! TADA!!!!! Same exception

So it looks like it is some sort of session problem but I don't know how to fix this. The documentation does not say anything about this issue.